# What is the "Find-Fix-Verify" pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

What is the "Find-Fix-Verify" pattern, as related to the process of doing editing/spellchecking/debugging, etc.?

Where is this pattern best described?

What are some advantages and disadvantages of this pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a workflow pattern for crowdsourcing, first described [in this paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/other-pubs/soylent.pdf) and used with some success by Zappos to [improve the spelling and grammar of product reviews](http://www.freakonomics.com/2011/04/12/does-reviewer-quality-matter/) on their site.

I guess the "pattern" is a simple division of labor:

- Have some people identify problems
- Have other people fix the problems identified by the first group
- Have a third group check that the fixes were done correctly

Makes sense (the find/fix division probably improves overall speed, and the verify step is always needed for crowdsourcing), but not really all that impressive an idea...